# Отправка в header x-auth через curl

Tags: php, curl

все ли я правильно делаю? Сервер куда я отправляю - не пускает меня. Есть подозрение, что либо x-auth-key не доходит, либо POST запросы.

Отправляю так:

```
 $fields = array( 'type' => 'buy');
  $postvars = '';
  foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
    $postvars .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
  }
    $headers = array();
$headers[] = "x-auth-key: ZTU1ODRjNzdasdasdasdKEYKEY";
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
$state_ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($state_ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://api.сайтсайт.com/account/orders");
    curl_setopt($state_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($state_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
    curl_setopt($state_ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $state_result = curl_exec ($state_ch);

    print_r($state_result);
```

Может можно другими функциями отправить (только стандартные)?

Comment: Вполне возможно, что все доходит, но сервер фильтрует заголовки и в скрипте их не видно.